# Ajax jquery post script not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am following this tutorial https://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107.
What i am trying to do is, use jquery and php to get data from a mysql database.
I exactly did what the tutorial said, but I am unable to make it work.
I get the fail alert when I load the page.

This is what I did:

**api.php:**

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db($db,$dbhandle)
or die("Could not select examples");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM todolist");
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo json_encode($array);
```

(I know that it is better to use `PDO`, but this is just for testing.)

**The jquery script:**

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
            $.ajax({                                      
              url: 'api.php', data: "", dataType: 'json',  
              success: function(data) { 
                var id = data[0]; 
                var description = data[1]; 
                 $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> description: </b>"+description); 
              },
              error: function() {
                alert("Fail");
              }
            });
          }); 
  </script>
```

When I visit `api.php` this is what I get:

```
["161","true","werken\n","12"]
```

when i use console.log(arguments) this shows up:

```
[Object, "parsererror", SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at Object.parse (native) at parseJSON …]
0
:
Object
1
:
"parsererror"
2
:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at Object.parse (native) at parseJSON (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js:16:11709) at b$ (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js:16:1382) at w (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js:18:8326) at XMLHttpRequest.d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js:18:14247)
callee
:
(err)
length
:
3
Symbol(Symbol.iterator)
:
values()
__proto__
:
Object
```

I am trying to make this work for about 3 hours now, and it drives me pretty crazy. I hope someone can explain the problem with my script.

**Edit:**

I fixed it. There was a problem with a page i included in api.php.

Comment: Press F12 in your browser to view the network request and make sure there are no errors and it looks like you expect, then look at the console to see if there are any errors there. Instead of `alert("Fail")` you could do `console.log(arguments)` to view all of the information passed to the `error` function to see if that shows you anything.

Comment: What do you see in developers console? Also, this is GET request, not POST.

Comment: BTW, it doesn't look like the description is in `data[1]`, it's in `data[2]`. You should either select the specific columns you want, or use `mysql_fetch_assoc` so you can access the columns by name.

Comment: @JasonP no errors are showing up in the console. But when i use console.log(arguments) something shows up, i add it to the question because it is too long.

Comment: Could you `console.log(data);`?

Comment: You're not looking in the right place to see console errors, because a parseError would definitely show up. Also, the error says that your response contains a `<` character ("`Unexpected token <`"), which means that the response is NOT what you expect. Look at the network tab and see what is being returned in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because of the url not using absolute path.
Are you running this on your local machine ? Are the 2 scripts (html and php) on the same directory ?

You should try to use the Developer Tool of your browser to check and track the network ajax call. You're probably getting a 404 error.

You could get more info on the error by doing this :

```
error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
```

The details of the errors will appear on your developer tool console. Most of the time, opening the developer tools is done by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I on PC, or by using browser menu.

Comment: This is on a website, the scripts are in the same directory. I am getting 0 errors. When i use console.log(err) this is showing up: 

Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<head>↵<meta property="og:image" c…↵    </script>↵["161","true","werken\n","12"]↵↵↵↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: So it means your php script does not return a JSON object. Apparently it returns a HTML page containing the JSON string in the body tag.